# Printing type(object) returns two statements In Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, breadth-first-search, attributeerror

```
def BFS(self, rootnode):
    visited = []
    queue = []
    queue.append(rootnode)
    while queue:
        print(type(queue))
        curr_node = (queue.pop())
        for node in curr_node.nodes:
            if node not in visited:
                visited.append(node)
                queue.append(node)
```

....

Hi, so I am trying to iterate through this trie object but I am having trouble iterating through its values. The data structure holds nodes, and
each node holds two values, a single character value and a dict of its children (which is held in nodes = {}).

I am currently getting an AttributeError: str has no attribute nodes at the line "for node in curr_node.nodes:"
I can't seem to figure out why. I checked the type of rootnodes which returned type Node. I checked the type of the first value of queue's nodes object which returned class dict. But when I try to iterate through that dict
I get the attribute error.
*I also know that each key in the dict is paired to a node.

Am I iterating through dicts properly?

*Here is the initial call
trie.BFS(trie.root.nodes['#'])

Thanks

Comment: "I checked the type of the first value of queue's nodes object" - what are you talking about? You only printed `type(queue)`.

Comment: Sorry, it was an omitted line of code: I had typed 'print(type(queue[0].nodes))' which returned the class dict

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the class definition of node, its hard to tell where the problem is. But if I have to guess, curr_node.nodes contains a str value.

The following slight change *might* help.

```
if node not in visited and not isinstance(node,str):                          
    visited.append(node)
    queue.append(node)
```

also, it would be more efficient if visited is a set.